# UIView multiple effects

Tags: iphone, performance, cocoa-touch, uiview, uikit

I'm working on iPad version of my application and I have a problem. I'd like to make a `UItableView` and `UIView` with multiple visual effects:

- Corner radius (3px)
- Inner shadow (black, 20%, 10px)
- Drop shadow (black, 30%, 5px)

The result has to be similar to built-in `Reminders.app` on iPad. This is a Photoshop preview of what I want to acheive:

[image]

As you can see (if you can't, open this image in 100% zoom), there is `UITableView` on the left and `UIView` on the right. Both views have corner radius, inner and drop shadows.

My question is: How can I acheive this effects programatically without loosing performance (when I tried to do this with `layer.cornerRadius` or `layer.shadow...` My TableView has lost its performance).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: practically, easiest and fastest way is to use images instead and make backgroundColor = clear color;

Comment: But I want theese views to chenge their frame programatically. Images will be disorted.

Comment: why would they get distortet ? you can define which part of the image should get stretched with stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:. so you can define a one pixel size which ist repeated for the whole heigt with plus the bottom and the top part of the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `shadowPath` on a layer is the lynchpin of good performance. It accepts a `CGPath`, so something like `self.tableView.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.tableView.bounds].CGPath;` should help considerably.

Comment: You didn't answer my question... How to make 3 effects **at once**?

Comment: I was addressing your concerns about performance during your original attempt. Inner shadows are tough without drawing it yourself. The drop shadow and corner radius can be achieved just by setting these properties on the table view's layer. For the inner shadow you could create a stretchable black on transparent image that can expand to any frame. Create an image that contains the shadow at the proper frame and set it as the contents of a new `CALayer`. Add that layer as a sublayer of the table view's layer. You may need to work at the UIKit level to handle animations to the frame change.

Comment: OK, I created an UIImageView and added it above table view. But when rotating my iPad frame property has a little bit ugly animation. It is not fluent.. Any suggestions?

Comment: OK, I realized that it's not UIImageView's fault. Thanks for suggestion!

Comment: For those who are not proficient in english (like a big part of the world population), **lynchpin** can be translated as "key".